# Is it possible to get direct print without preview of the pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, printing

I am developing a custom report where line items are coming with a check-box in front of each item. User can select single/multiple line-items by checking those check-boxes. The report also has a PRINT button in application tool bar by clicking which a pdf will be printing for each item. Thats mean, for 10 selected line items, 10 forms will be printed.

But, after clicking the PRINT button, print preview of the form is coming and from there I can go for a print/printer. I do not need the print preview and want to have the direct print option while clicking the PRINT button. How can I have this functionality?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check this answer: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print>

Comment: if use  from client side u check window.print()