# How to avoid print popup window and print directly to default printer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am trying to print the content of my `Div`.

Below is my `js` and `html` code.

```js
function printContent(el){
 var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
 var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

```html
<h1>My page</h1>
<div id="div1">DIV 1 content...</div>
<button onclick="printContent('div1')">Print Content</button>
<div id="div2">DIV 2 content...</div>
<button onclick="printContent('div2')">Print Content</button>
<p id="p1">Paragraph 1 content...</p>
<button onclick="printContent('p1')">Print Content</button>
```

I just want to avoid the print popup so that printing goes directly to default printer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a printer and silently print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print)