# Direct Print after clicking

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a JS function in my POS website which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printlayer(layer){
  var generator=window.open(",'name,");
  var layertext=document.getElementById(layer);
  generator.document.write(layertext.innerHTML.replace('Print Me'));
  generator.document.close();
  generator.print();
  generator.close();
}
```

When I click on Print button, it opens a new Print tab on screen but I want to print directly. Suppose I clicked on print, it should print directly.
"IT SHOULD NOT OPEN THE PRINT TAB".
I am using Thermal Receipt Printer:
GPrinter
Modal is: GP80160II
Paper width: 80mm
Print Speed: 160mm/sec.

This Picture is before clicking Print:
[image]

This Picture is After clicking (That I don't want):
[image]
Please Help me. I am not able to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling `window.open()`. If you want to print directly, don't do that. Just call `print()`. If necessary, hide everything you don't want to print, for instance by using @media rules.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried `.print` also, but there are some issues. It shows popup print screen

Comment: @ChrisG see my question now. I Added Pictures now.

Comment: I created a PHP app for a friend to print A4 invoices; the key is to use CSS like `width: 19cm` so the screen document translates 1:1 to paper.

Comment: That is how chrome works and how any other browser would. You can't do anything about it

Comment: Oh, I see, you're asking how to skip the print dialog? You can't.

Comment: @ChrisG there is no way to do this or any other method ???

Comment: No, however PHP can directly print to a printer on the server. So if this is for a local or intranet app, you could print directly on a printer connected to the server.

Comment: But PHP don't accept the URDU language... I want receipt in urdu

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IE browser then this can be achieved. But in firefox and chrome we can't bypass the dialogue box. You can avoid the print dialog from any application by using some cloud printing REST API.

[Select a printer and silently print(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print)

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces

https://www.printnode.com/docs/api/curl/