# How to skip browser default print preview and print content directly to printer in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As, we know in C# windows form application we can print content directly to print without any preview. I want to print content in jQuery/JavaScript when user click a button, browser does not show any print preview and content printed to printer.

Comment: Why do this - and not offer the user the possibility of saving paper/ink?

Comment: I want to print tokens and client don't like the print preview again and again.

Comment: browser does not let you to do that, but you can force to download it like <a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a> in c# sharp you can directly send parameters to printer but in web , browser will send parameters.

Comment: @MujassirNasir did you find a solution? I want the same directly print, in my case I have a kiosk like setup -> Scan ticket -> print pdf ? Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers will not allow that to happen. You can use the below plugin to provide beautiful previews.

https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin

Demo: http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html

Comment: Is there anyway to do this by creating some chrome extension?

Comment: I don't think so. Ultimately you'll have to print the page at which stage the browser will show preview screen.

Answer (score 11):

After hours of research I found following solutions to resolve my issue.

Maybe you could setup your printers with Google Clound Print then use the cloud printing API to silently submit jobs to them. It looks like you can specify the printer id when you submit the job. You might need to use something like html2canvas to rasterize the webpage.

Found here [Select a printer and silently print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print)

In chrome (v18+) we have the --kiosk --kiosk-printing switches. One can print automatically to default printer without print confirmation.

You can see it from this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6UHjuvI7IE

Found here [Google Chrome Extension: Print the page silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849952/google-chrome-extension-print-the-page-silently/9320649#9320649)

Comment: ah here is your solution. Sounds promising, do you still know the video title as your link is dead?

Comment: Video is not available now

Answer (score 1):

it is posible in IE with VBScript script, just put it into your page.

```
<script type="text/VBScript" language="VBScript">
        Sub Print()
               OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
               OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
               OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
               call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
        End Sub
        document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function() { 
        window.print();
        self.close();
   }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me perfectly. If you are using Mozilla Firefox navigate to config files by typing `about:config` in search bar and hit enter. You will be directed to a page with firefox settings and search for `print.always_print_silent`. To disable print preview change the boolean value to true and to enable change to true.

It worked for me. In chrome use --kiosk printing.

For more visit https://support.aerocrs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360030321912-Firefox-browser-bypassing-the-print-dialog-box-

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible by following plugins, and then call java script while printing.

1- QZ Tray ( https://qz.io )

2- JS Print Manager ( https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-HTML-from-Javascript-to-client-printer-without-print-dialog-silently/ )