# I want page going to print directly instead of print preview page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Print button:

```
<button type="button" id="btnPrint" style="background-color:lightblue" value="Print">Print</button>
```

on click of this button my existing page navigate to print i dont want print preview window directly navigate to printer.

Comment: <button type="button" id="btnPrint" style="background-color:lightblue" value="Print">Print</button> my bootstrap code is here

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer

Comment: thnks but not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip browser default print preview and print content directly to printer in jquery/javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer)

Comment: i need another option.is there any jquery code