# printThis - do not ask for printer selection

Tags: printthis

Using printThis.js library, is there an option to NOT display the printer selection dialog?

I would simply like to print to the default printer, using the default parameters.

This question is focused on the PrintThis.js library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip browser default print preview and print content directly to printer in jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/issues/184#issuecomment-510520318

> For security reasons your browser requires that the print dialog
>   prompt before printing, otherwise any website could print without
>   permission. printThis cannot override this behavior.
>
> There are some use cases where printing without the dialog is desired
>   (such as a kiosk), but printThis would have no control over that
>   behavior, and the kiosk setup would need to account for it through
>   print settings, etc.