# Native messaging from chrome extension to native host written in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to receive a message from my chrome extension via native messaging. The `popup.html` console indicates that the message is being sent, but my host is not receiving it for some reason. I can see that the host `native.exe` is being launched in task manager, but the host is not receive the sent data.

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var downloadButton= document.getElementById('Button');
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "myScript.js"}, function (data) {
                sendNativeMessage(data[0]);
            });
        });
    });
});

function sendNativeMessage(msg) {
    var hostName = "com.google.example";

    console.log("Connecting to host: " + hostName);
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);

    message = {"text": msg};
    port.postMessage(message);

    console.log("Sent message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

Now, when I send the message from my Chrome Extension, I can see the console log for `popup.html` and the message is correct.

I tried to test everything by using some code that someone claimed to have worked, from [Native Messaging Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219144/native-messaging-chrome). Specifically, I have

**native.exe**

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        while (OpenStandardStreamIn() != null || OpenStandardStreamIn() != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(OpenStandardStreamIn());
        }
    }

    private static string OpenStandardStreamIn()
    {
        //Read first four bytes for length information
        System.IO.Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        int length = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
        length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

        string input = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();

        return input;
    }
```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around nativeMessaging, but since I can see the message being sent via the console logs, I have to assume the error is with my `.exe`. I have created the registry keys, HKCU, and created the host's `manifest.json` file. Since the extension is launching the `.exe`, I'm pretty sure all of that is working fine as well.

If anyone could provide some assistance with this, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** After changing absolutely nothing, I cannot get my `native.exe` to launch anymore from my extension. In an effort to fix this, I tried rewriting my sender to not open a port:

```
...
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "myScript.js"}, function (data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.google.example', {"text":data[0]}, function(response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
            console.log("ERROR");
        } else {
            console.log("Response: " + response);
        }
    });
});
...
```

This doesn't work at all either. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, or why my host `.exe` stopped launching when I sent a message from my extension.

---

**EDIT #2**

Good news!

I deleted my registry key and then added it again, this time into the Local Machine registry (i.e. HKLM). Again, I used the code from [Native Messaging Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219144/native-messaging-chrome) to send and receive from my host. Now, when I look at my extension's log, I can see the correct response from my host. I am using the "no-port" method by simply calling `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(...)`, which is fine for my purposes. Unfortunately, I am not receiving the message FROM the extension TO the host. Also, my `host.exe` never exits, even after the message has been received. I'm not sure why, but if anyone can help out, I would appreciate it.

In my host, I'm attempting to write the incoming message to a file just to test that I'm getting the message:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path_to_file.txt", OpenStandardStreamIn());
```

Note: The message that I'm passing FROM the extension TO the host is around 250KB (it varies from message to message).

The problem is:

1. ***Nothing is written to the file. It's completely blank.***
2. The file takes a long time to create (~4 seconds).
3. My `host.exe` instance never terminates. It's still running (I can view it in the task manager).

Comment: Have you tried logging `chrome.runtime.lastError.message`?

Comment: @Xan Yes. I get a `specified native messaging host not found` error. I've created my key in the HKCU registry and pointed it to my `host-manifest.json`, which I've stored in the same directory as my `host.exe` just for good measure. Also, yesterday, when I sent a message from my extension, an instance of `host.exe` was showing up in the taskmgr, so I'm not sure why it broke.

Comment: @Xan I fixed the `host not found` error, but now I'm stuck on actually receiving the message from the Chrome extension. I'm also trying to figure out why my `host.exe` is not terminating after the file is created. See Edit #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get my extension working, I followed the following steps:

1. I deleted my registry key and then re-added it in my HKLM registry.
2. Although unnecessary,`host.exe` really only needed to receive one message from the extension, so I changed my previous "open port" messaging to a "no port" message, i.e.

   `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(...);`
3. Importantly, when I changed the text I was sending from `{"text":data[0]}` to a simple string `{"text":"Hello from Chrome!"}`, everything began working smoothly. `data[0]` was a string of about 250KB, which should definitely be an acceptable message size according to the [developer's site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). However, I have created a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653624/passing-large-amount-of-data-from-chrome-extension-to-host-written-in-c) for this problem, as I was able to solve the general message sending and receiving problem I was experiencing.