# How to print webpage without print preview on ButtonClick using Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I wrote this code but still print preview option is coming...

`this.contentWindow.print()` for printing purpose

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script>
   function printPage()
   {
      var div = document.getElementById("printerDiv");
      div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="PrintDemo.aspx" onload="this.contentWindow.print();"></iframe>';
   }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button onclick="printPage()">prin`enter code here`t</button>
<div id="printerDiv" ">
    This Page Is for print demo`enter code here`
</div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. It's a client thing.

Comment: This may work only on Chrome- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849952/google-chrome-extension-print-the-page-silently/9320649#9320649. Try and check in other browsers as well